Code suggestions not working on IntelliJ IDEA for fxml files
Autocompletion/code suggestions for .fxml files in IntelliJ IDEA are not working.
I tried to open project on other machines with latest IntelliJ IDEA (2024.1), it works. I using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3

It is working on ohter machines, but I used other version of IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate/Community 2024.1) instead of that in my machine - Ultimate 2022.3.3. On my computer it not works properly

Maybe you should update your 2 years old IDEA to the newest version first.

@DavidWeber Yes, maybe, but i have no license for IDEA Ultimate to update and not able to buy it.

The Community Edition can not autocomplete fxml. I recommend you to configure and use SceneBuilder for editing fxml files.

Problem has solved by resetting all IDEA settings and autocompletion now works with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.

There is bundled JavaFX plugin in newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA. It fully supoprts .fxml files.
The plugin also available in IntelliJ IDEA Community.
